# The topos for forcing in computability theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, topos-theory

My understanding is that forcing (such as Cohen forcing) can be described via a topos.  For example this [nlab article on forcing](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/forcing) describes forcing as a "the topos of sheaves on a suitable site."

My question concerns forcing in computability theory, for example as described in Chapter 3 or these [lecture notes of Richard Shore](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~shore/papers/pdf/SingLect2NS.pdf).  The idea is that the generics are those which meet all *computable* dense sets of forcing conditions.  (Computable can mean a few things.  Often it is taken to mean a $\Sigma^0_1$ set of forcing conditions.  Also, usually the forcing posets are countable.)  Since there are only countably many such dense sets, such effective generics exist.

> Is there a known/canonical type of topos corresponding to the forcing in computability theory?

Any references would be appreciated.

*FYI: My background is in computability theory, proof theory, and computable analysis.  I know little about topos theory, but I am willing to learn a bit.  I am mostly asking this question because I want to compare some ideas I have about effective versions of Solovay forcing with some work by others about the topos corresponding to Solovay forcing.  Also, it is always nice to learn new things.*

Comment: Did you also want the forcing partial order to be a (close to) computable relation?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen, I would be happy to know the answer in that case.  (The application I have in mind is a bit more general, but I think knowing what is going on in the case of a computable forcing poset is sufficient for me to get a general idea of what is going on.)

Comment: Have you, since asking the question two years ago, learned about a topos-theoretic treatment of forcing in computability theory?